# Mega Menu with PHP in Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, megamenu

**EDIT**: Based on the advice by Tom, here's my modified code. Works well, so thanks Tom.

```
<?php
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->get();

    foreach($categories as $category):

        $category_courses = get_courses($category->id);
        $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
        $max_iteration = ceil(count($sub_categories) / 4);
?>
    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu style-plain">
            <li class="one-column">
                <?php foreach($sub_categories as $key=>$sub_category): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-title">{{ $sub_category->name }}</li>
                        <?php foreach(get_courses($sub_category->id) as $course): ?>
                            <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php if(($key + 1) % $max_iteration == 0): ?>
                        </li>
                        <li class="one-column">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Though now I'm thinking I should create a tree in memory after getting some advice from machuga in the #laravel IRC. Essentially based on this SO answer [Flat PHP Array to Hierarchy Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740429/flat-php-array-to-hierarchy-tree).

---

I'm trying to create a mega menu in my Laravel app with the following structure, so that it works well with Bootstrap 2.3.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4 transition">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">$category <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="one-column">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 1</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 1</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one-column">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 2</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 2</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one-column">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 3</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 3</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="one-column">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 4</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="nav-title">$subCategory 4</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">$course</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my database I have the following:

```
table: categories
fields: id, parent_id, name, slug

table: courses
fields: id, category_id, title, slug
```

I am struggling with the for and foreach loop logic in order to generate the ul elements within the li:one-column elements. I want a maximum of 4 columns, with as many rows as necessary, depending on how many sub-categories there are.

So, in the categories table a top level category will not have a 'parent_id' assigned to it but a sub-category will have a top level 'parent_id' assigned to it.

So I can foreach through $categories as $category and setup the top level menu structure which will create a li:dropdown element for each top level category. The problem comes when trying to implement the li:one-column elements. Each li:one-column element is essentially a column in the mega menu, so I need a maximum of four. Each ul within the column is a sub-category.

So if there are 13 sub-categories under the top level category, each column will have the following:

```
Column 1: 4
Column 2: 3
Column 3: 3
Column 4: 3
```

Then if a new sub-category were added, it would be:

```
Column 1: 4
Column 2: 4
Column 3: 3
Column 4: 3
```

And so on. So essentially each new sub-category would fill up the next available column.

There's probably a really easy solution to this but I'm struggling with the logic at the minute. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I'm getting closer using:

```
    <ul class="nav">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <?php
                            $category_courses = get_courses($category->id);
                            $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
                            $sub_categories_total = count($sub_categories); // int(5)
                            $sub_category_split = round($sub_categories_total / 4); // int(1)
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu style-plain">
                                    @for($i=0; ++$i <=4;)
                                    <li class="one-column">
                                            @foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category)
                                                            <ul >
                                                                    <li class="nav-title">{{ $sub_category->name }}</li>
                                                                    @foreach(get_courses($sub_category->id) as $course)
                                                                            <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
                                                                    @endforeach
                                                            </ul>
                                            @endforeach
                                    </li>
                                    @endfor
                            </ul>
                    </li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
```

I'm still not quite there though, as it adds all sub_categories to each li:one-column element. I feel I'm certainly closer to a solution though.

**EDIT**: OK, I'm a lot closer now. I'm now able to output only the maximum iteration in each li:one-column element but it outputs exactly the same data. I need a way to continue the foreach loop from where it breaks.

```
<ul class="nav">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <?php
                            $category_courses = get_courses($category->id);
                            $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
                            $max_iteration = round(count($sub_categories) / 4);
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu style-plain">
                                    @for($ci=0; ++$ci <=4;)
                                            <li class="one-column">
                                                    @foreach($sub_categories as $key=>$sub_category)
                                                            @if($key <= $max_iteration)
                                                                    <ul >
                                                                            <li class="nav-title">{{ $sub_category->name }}</li>
                                                                            @foreach(get_courses($sub_category->id) as $course)
                                                                                    <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
                                                                            @endforeach
                                                                    </ul>
                                                            @else
                                                                    <?php break; ?>
                                                            @endif
                                                    @endforeach
                                            </li>
                                    @endfor
                            </ul>
                    </li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
```

**EDIT**: OK, this is the closest I've got so far and it's almost there. Still not right though, as it outputs 1 subcategory in the first column, column 2, column 3 but 2 in column 4. :-(

```
    @foreach($categories as $category)
            <?php
                    $category_courses = get_courses($category->id);
                    $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
                    $max_iteration = round(count($sub_categories) / 4) + 1;
            ?>
            <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu style-plain">
                            <li class="one-column">
                                    @foreach($sub_categories as $key=>$sub_category)
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li class="nav-title">{{ $sub_category->name }}</li>
                                                    @foreach(get_courses($sub_category->id) as $course)
                                                            <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
                                                    @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                            @if($key <= $max_iteration)
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="one-column">
                                            @endif
                                    @endforeach
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to count the total sub-categories and then create some logic to evenly split them across the li:one-column elements.

Comment: So this is where I'm struggling. I need to foreach $sub_categories as $sub_category so I can get access to the properties of each sub-category but I need to be able to escape out of the foreach loop if it reaches a certain integer value and then start again where it left off in a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes to achieve this. Firstly, you might need to use `ceil` instead of `round` for your `$max_iteration` variable. This will ensure your columns always split in a consistent place.

Then, change this line...

```
@if($key <= $max_iteration)
```

to

```
@if(($key + 1) % $max_iteration == 0)
```

$key is a key starting at zero, so you need to increment it, as we're dealing with quantities starting at 1. Then, by checking its remainder when divided by `$max_iteration`, we can tell if we've reached the next column. It will be zero when the key is a multiple of max iteration.

Comment: Chers Tom you legend.

Answer (score 0):

Having understood a little more what you're looking for, I think this may be more appropriate, so think of it as a separator:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
                    <?php
                            $category_courses = get_courses($category->id);
                            $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
                            $max_iteration = round(count($sub_categories) / 4);
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu style-plain">
                                            <li class="one-column">
                        <?php $counter = 0 ?>
                                                    @foreach($sub_categories as $key=>$sub_category)
                            <?php  $counter++ ?>
                                    @if($counter == $max_iteration) 
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="one-column">
                                       <?php $counter = 0;?>
                                    @endif
                                                                    <ul >
                                                                            <li class="nav-title">{{ $sub_category->name }}</li>
                                                                            @foreach(get_courses($sub_category->id) as $course)
                                                                                    <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
                                                                            @endforeach
                                                                    </ul>
                                                    @endforeach


                                            </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Not really, as this will output all subcategories in to one column, whereas I need them split over 4 columns.

Comment: Is this not configured with how you associate the parent/child relationship with the categories?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to achieve exactly. The columns in the menu are not related to anything in the database. I need to split the subcategories evenly across 4 columns in the HTML. See my edit above. So say I have 5 sub_categories. I need a way of sharing them equally across the columns, so that column 1 has 2 sub_category ul elements, and the rest have 1. Do you get what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Think I have a clearer idea now. I'd recommend just observing the regular loop and inserting the li breaks where necessary - probably need more sophisticated maths than what I've presented but I hope its what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks man. Very close indeed. The only issue is it adds 6 columns instead of 4, should only ever have 4 li:column-one elements. One of those extra columns is an empty one right at the beginning.

Comment: It's already generating 4 columns with no issue. The problem is the subcategories are not being split evenly across the columns.