# Symfony 2 - querybuilder nested tree array

Tags: symfony

Here is scenario:

```
   id  parent_id  search
   1   null       hello
   2   1          hello/something
   3   1          hello/new
   4   null       new
   5   4          new/hello
```

Then I got via querybuilder and searching "hello" to this results:

```
   1   null       hello
   2   1          hello/something
   3   1          hello/new
   5   4          new/hello
   5   4          new/hello
```

How to build nested tree via querybuilder if I want only get all elements inside childs, include "hello/something" ?

How to build up using symfony to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Doctrine, check out the [tree extension in DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md)

Comment: I don't want to use Doctrine, I know for this, but i'm using LIKE statements.

Comment: If you can't use the doctrine extension, then just get it as an array and then look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740843/582278).