# Reorder multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a a script that reads form a DB table

**Current Output:**

```
{ ["id"]=>"1" ["name"]=> "USER 1" ["parentID"]=>"0" }
{ ["id"]=>"7" ["name"]=> "USER 7" ["parentID"]=>"1" }
{ ["id"]=>"3" ["name"]=> "USER 3" ["parentID"]=>"1" }
{ ["id"]=>"6" ["name"]=> "USER 6" ["parentID"]=>"3" }
{ ["id"]=>"2" ["name"]=> "USER 2" ["parentID"]=>"3" }
{ ["id"]=>"5" ["name"]=> "USER 5" ["parentID"]=>"4" }
{ ["id"]=>"8" ["name"]=> "USER 8" ["parentID"]=>"5" }
{ ["id"]=>"9" ["name"]=> "USER 9" ["parentID"]=>"6" }
{ ["id"]=>"4" ["name"]=> "USER 4" ["parentID"]=>"7" }
```

I read from the database in the ascending order for the parent ID, I need to reorder them so that a child will be below the parent ID so for instance  USER 4 should be after USER 7 as USER 4 has the parent ID 7.

**Expected Output:**

```
{ ["id"]=>"1" ["name"]=> "USER 1" ["parentID"]=>"0" }    
{ ["id"]=>"7" ["name"]=> "USER 7" ["parentID"]=>"1" }    
{ ["id"]=>"4" ["name"]=> "USER 4" ["parentID"]=>"7" }    
{ ["id"]=>"3" ["name"]=> "USER 3" ["parentID"]=>"1" }    
{ ["id"]=>"6" ["name"]=> "USER 6" ["parentID"]=>"3" }    
{ ["id"]=>"2" ["name"]=> "USER 2" ["parentID"]=>"3" }    
{ ["id"]=>"5" ["name"]=> "USER 5" ["parentID"]=>"4" }    
{ ["id"]=>"8" ["name"]=> "USER 8" ["parentID"]=>"5" }    
{ ["id"]=>"9" ["name"]=> "USER 9" ["parentID"]=>"6" }
```

**My code:**

```
$list = [];
$db = Db::getInstance();

$req = $db->query('SELECT * FROM staff');

foreach($req->fetchAll() as $staff) {

    $data['id'] = $staff['ID'];
    $data['name'] = $staff['name'];
    $data['parentID'] = $staff['ParentID'];

    array_push($list,$data);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the database table

Comment: There is a good example of a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740429/flat-php-array-to-hierarchy-tree

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740429/flat-php-array-to-hierarchy-tree solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the database query to handle the sort.

```
 SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY id, parentID;
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work as the parentID isn't in numerical order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes