# How to create nested list from PHP array for dropdown select field?

Tags: php, list, nested

My problem is very similar to the one described here in this topic [Create nested list from PHP array for dropdown select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613546/create-nested-list-from-php-array-for-dropdown-select-field/) The problem is that if investments are not consecutive, then incorrectly adds a dash

```
function buildTree(Array $data, $parent = 0) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        if ($d['parent'] == $parent) {
            $children = buildTree($data, $d['id']);
            // set a trivial key
            if (!empty($children)) {
                $d['_children'] = $children;
            }
            $tree[] = $d;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

function printTree($tree, $r = 0, $p = null) {
    foreach ($tree as $i => $t) {
        $dash = ($t['parent'] == 0) ? '' : str_repeat('-', $r) .' ';
        printf("\t<option value='%d'>%s%s</option>\n", $t['id'], $dash, $t['name']);
        if ($t['parent'] == $p) {
            // reset $r
            $r = 0;
        }
        if (isset($t['_children'])) {
            printTree($t['_children'], ++$r, $t['parent']);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works for such a structure array

```
$rows = array(
    array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test 1', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test 1.1', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test 1.2', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.1', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2.1', 'parent' => 5),
    array ('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Test 2', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Test 2.1', 'parent' => 7),
);
```

But does not work for this

```
$rows = array(
    array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test 1', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test 1.1', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test 1.2', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.1', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2.1', 'parent' => 5),
    array ('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Test 2', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Test 2.1', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 9, 'name' => 'another data', 'parent' => 1),
);
```

How can I change it? sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are not setting the "parent" attribute right. Even if the name is "Test 2.1", using this algorithm, you have to set the parent index. If you change your array to this, it'll work:

```
$rows = array(
    array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test 1', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test 1.1', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test 1.2', 'parent' => 1),
    array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.1', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2', 'parent' => 3),
    array ('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Test 1.2.2.1', 'parent' => 5),
    array ('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Test 2', 'parent' => 0),
    array ('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Test 2.1', 'parent' => 7),
    array ('id' => 9, 'name' => 'another data with no parent', 'parent' => 0),
);
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in how to change the function to work with my array.

Comment: You didn't say how you expect your array to work, neither showed a sample of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved your problem [here on SO in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21511495/2655631)

just replace `++$r` with `$r+1`

the "dash" now works great.